# How can I start download file after page.render()?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

The download starts before file(*.pdf) render. How can I start download file after it will be rendered?

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.open("http://localhost:3000", function(status) {
            if (status !== 'success') {
                console.log('Unable to access the network!');
            } else {
                page.render('filename.pdf');
            }
            ph.exit();
        });
    });
});

res.download('filename.pdf');
```

**Edit1**
I solved my problem, not the best decision but it's works for me

```
var downloadRe = function (){
setTimeout(function(){
        res.download('name.pdf', function(err){
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    downloadRe();
                },1000);
            } else { 
                fs.unlink('name.pdf',function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
        });
    },1000);
}
downloadRe();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node is by default an asynchronous engine. You probably have a race condition. I don't have any experience with phantomJS, but I would think that you'll have to have a download request on the client side after the page is fully rendered to achieve your desired effect. Otherwise, you cannot possibly know about the state of the page's rendering from the server.

Comment: The problem is I want to do this in POST response. Maybe some hacks or something like this ?  Alternatively i can try "setTimeout" but i think it's not the best variant...

Comment: Are you triggering the post via ajax? If so, then perhaps, depending on your framework if it supports deferred objects, you could chain this. An example using jQuery, for instance, might be
$.post(<send request to view PDF>).then(<send request to download file>). Now this might not give the desired effect (you might need to use complete instead of status ready), but the point being is that this needs to be done on the client side.